# Replacing entire string with uppercase Character in C++

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm seeking help in replacing characters in an entire string. I'm looking to replace all the characters in a string with an uppercase X. I tried implementing the range for loop, however it seems this is not supported by Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 as I experience errors. So I decided to use a standard `for` loop, I also tried to use the replace string function which I assumed will be inbuilt in string function library. However, I received errors. I will be grateful for any help. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
const char ch = 'X';
char Char1;
string str = {"This is my Book"};

string::size_type n;
for(n = 0; n < str.size(); ++n){ 
    if(str[n] == Char1)
        str[n] = ch;
    cout<< str << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What value do you think `Char1` has?

Comment: `if(str[n] == Char1)` how is this supposed to work? `Char1` is uninitialized. Just remove the `if()` control block to replace **all** the charactes in `str` (there are only characters BTW.)

Comment: `std::string strX = std::string( str.size(), 'X'); str = strX;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want to replace each character by an X. 
A string is composed wholly of characters and so your question doesn't make much sense. I am assuming you mean that you want to replace all alphabets (lower case and upper case) by X.

You for loop can be re-written like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < str.size(); ++
    if (((str[n] < 91) && (str[n] > 64)) || ((str[n] < 123) && (str[n] > 96)))
          str[n] = 'X';
```

The comparisions with 91, 64, 123 and 96 correspond to the upper and lower limit for ASCII value of upper case and lower case alphabets.

PS: If you mean't something else, let me know and I will modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Using `'a'`, `'z'`, `'A'`, and `'Z'` saves you a comment in code and in this answer.

Comment: @llnspectable: True that. Although I wasn't really sure if that would work, and I though that this was the safer way of posting it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @therainmaker And be aware, that the OP will ask you to fix their 1st place problems (compiler errors) as well.

Answer (score 2):

In general, *I receive errors* is NOT very descriptive, and your code is HORRIBLY indented. However, the error is here:

```
string str = {"This is my Book"};
```

You probably meant:

```
string str {"This is my Book"};
```

The former creates an initializer list and tries to assign it to `str`; the latter just constructs a string with the given argument.

However, VS 2010 does not support initializer lists, so you need to do this:

```
string str("This is my Book");
```

Also, you have a redundant opening brace in your for loop that's never matched with a closing one.

Another issue: `Char1` is never initialized, so it can hold anything at all. It seems useless in its current context, too.

Your `for` loop would also be better done using an STL iterator:

```
for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    *it = ch;
```

Your fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char ch = 'X';
    string str("This is my Book");

    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
        // for each character in str, set it to ch
        *it = ch;
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to replace only letters, do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char ch = 'X';
    string str("This is my Book");

    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
        if (isalpha(*it)) // make sure we're replacing a letter
            *it = ch;
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, since you're just filling a string, there's a better way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char ch = 'X';
    string str("This is my Book");

    str = string(str.size(), 'X');
    // This is a version of the std::string constructor that takes
    // a number (N) and a character and duplicates the character N
    // times.
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or, better yet, use lambdas and for_each:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char ch = 'X';
    string str("This is my Book");

    // for_each takes an iterator to the start and end of any STL
    // container. It then calls the given function on each element in 
    // the iterator. This lambda replaces the character with ch.
    for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char& c) { c = ch; });
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I visited a site to learn about iterators, from what I read the iterator deals with containers  and the str.begin() and end begins and end th iteration. On the second code, why is the scope operator used with the string definition instead of the _ assignment. Also I read about the isalpha function that it checks if an element  is an alphabet letter. So i guess the if statement checks if the element in the address is an alphabet letter and places the X in the address location. Thanks

Comment: @dirty_sanchez I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have the code working nicely.